# Sufficient condition to have integrating factor a function of $x+y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

What will be the sufficient condition for the differential equation $M(x,y)\,dx + N(x,y)\,dy =0$ to have an integrating factor as a function of $(x+y).$ What will be integrating factor in that case?

I got struck at $ \frac{ f(x+y)}{f'(x+y)} = \frac{(dM/dy - dN/dx)}{(N-M)}$.
 How to proceed further??

Comment: Questions posted here should not be phrased in language suitable for assigning homework. You should show that you have some thoughts of your own.

Comment: Ok sir. It was a mistake on my behalf.